# What is Shortcut Key for Import Data in SASEG

Tags: sas

i just want to know what is the shortcut keys for Import Data Window of SAS EG (Sas Enterprise Guide)
(Windows)

I know its  a basic question, but i really try to find the shortcut key on the internet but i dint find one , i really need to know the shortcut key to open that Window

[image]